# Python testing by asserting consistent behavior across code revisions?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tox

A typical Python unit test asserts that some function returns a pre-computed output value, e.g.:

```py
def average(a, b):
    return (a + b) / 2

def test_average():
    assert average(2, 4) == 3
```

Assertion tests all follow this same basic formula: Supply inputs, supply expected outputs, invoke the code to be tested, compare. I write tests like this frequently, and I think their value in many cases is obvious.

But I'm uneasy about the ambiguity test frameworks leave around how exactly the asserted result (`3` in the example) is meant to be computed. In a test, you often want a variety of parameters to show off edge-case behavior, e.g.:

```py
def test_average(a, b):
    params = [
        [1, 3, 2],
        [9000.5, 9000.5, 9000.5], 
        [100, -100, 0],
        [-1, 3, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]
    ]
    for a, b, result in params:
        assert average(a, b) == result
```

But if you have either a long parameter list or a difficult-to-compute result, you have to choose between two options:

1. Run the code-under-test once manually, e.g. from IPython, and preserve its return value in the codebase as a test assertion
2. Reimplement enough of the code-under-test that expected results are computed in the test case itself

Most developers use a combination of both approaches. But neither gives you much evidence that the code is *correct*, only that it is *consistent* across revisions of code. Running your tests really just tests that code behaves the same way it did when the tests were authored.

This made me wonder if there are test practices where recording/comparing runtime behavior across revisions (to the software under test) is made explicit. For example, you could write a JSON collection of "demo case" return values to disk and version control, so test cases could then assert properties about the consistency of these results across versions:

```py
def demo_average():
    arg_a_vals = [0, -4.2, 1/12] + range(-100, 1000, 5)
    arg_b_vals = [0, -10**200, math.pi] + range(2**20, 2**20 + 17)
    return [
        a, b, average(a, b)
        for a in arg_a_vals
        for b in arg_b_vals
    ]

def save_demo(results):
    with open(f"demo_v{__version__}.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(results, f)

def load_demo(version):
    with open(f"demo_v{version}.json") as f:
        return json.load(f)

def test_average():
    result = demo_average()
    save_demo(result)
    saved_result = load_demo(GOOD_PRIOR_VERSION)
    assert_lists_are_equal(result, saved_result)
```

This example is intentionally simple, but `save_demo`, `load_demo`, and `test_average` could be generalized so the only code you need to repeat in each test case is some variant of `demo_average` — an enumeration of possible input values whose outputs should be compared across revisions. Note that the code does *not* include any expected output values as literals, unlike a normal assertion test.

You could also avoid needing to commit "demo" results (which are potentially very large) if the test framework is aware of the version control system and can run demos on multiple cloned versions to generate the `results` object above on the fly.

**Are there any Python test frameworks or projects that work like this?** That is, where software is tested by verifying that the code returns **consistent results across revisions to the code**, rather than having a specific expected result asserted in the test case. [Edit: Dirk Hermann notes in the comments this is sometimes known as **back-to-back testing**.]

Note that I've looked into [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I'm not sure it addresses this use case. It supports cross-version comparisons, but the docs mostly consider ensuring your own existing test cases pass under multiple versions of your project's dependencies, which I don't think applies.

A few people have also mentioned [Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Hypothesis is interesting, and also works very differently than normal tests — briefly, you write tests as highly parameterized/generalized assertions and Hypothesis does clever things to explore the parameter space for failures. But from reading the docs I can't see how this applies to my case. My goal is to write tests that assert version-to-version consistency of behavior, not check any properties that could be asserted about a single version of the code in isolation.

Comment: Maybe something like [Hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: Hm. Maybe I'm missing something. `doctest` + `tox` + .. `git`? No? **"Consistency across versions"** of what? Across versions of code, versions of python, both?

Comment: @snakecharmerb  "that test code by programmatically recording output of test cases" - I'm not sure I understand this absolutely clear but do `hypothesis` have such facilities?

Comment: @AlexYu I believe it does - https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#the-hypothesis-example-database

Comment: `assert test_average(a, b)` => `assert average(a, b)` (2 times).

Comment: The strategy you want to apply is also known as back-to-back testing - maybe that helps in finding solutions on the web...

Comment: Calling functions from the SUT in your tests is not generally a problem, given that you only use functions that are otherwise thoroughly tested.  For example, for testing methods, you will simply not get away without calling the constructor...

Comment: @AlexYu I edited/expanded my question to clarify. I mean consistency across revisions to the software-under-test itself — the code you're actually developing. I'm not talking about package dependencies or Python versions.

Comment: @phd Thank you, good catch — fixed.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann It looks for me that `back-to-back testing` is agnostic to libraries/programming language/platform - it declares that results must be consistent no matter how software was written, am I right? It must be possible to use the same procedure for testing solutions of differrent vendors/teams. Correct me if I wrong please.

Comment: @AlexYu That is also my understanding - but as with many terms, there can be different not-quite-identical definitions outside.  The definition from ISTQB at least has no limitations wrt. language/platform: http://glossary.istqb.org/search/back-to-back.  It is quite simple: Run the same test cases on different versions, compare the results - that's all.  It could even mean that version A is in Java, version B is ported to Python, and if you also port the test code from A to B, that would logically be the same test cases.  Thus comparing the two outputs would classify as back-to-back testing.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann So the question is outside of python. Maybe it's better to ask it on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) or(and) [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com)